# How to use MySQL SOUNDEX function with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, soundex

Looking for any example of making SOUNDEX queries on MySQL from SQLAlchemy, if possible at all. Any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is to use the [`SOUNDEX()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex) function, then just use [`func`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.func) to generate the function expression:

```
session.query(func.soundex(MyModel.some_str))
```

If on the other hand you need the [`SOUNDS LIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#operator_sounds-like) operator, you can use [`op()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnElement.op):

```
session.query(MyModel).\
    filter(MyModel.some_str.op('SOUNDS LIKE')('Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious'))
```

which is equivalent to

```
session.query(MyModel).\
    filter(func.soundex(MyModel.some_str) ==
           func.soundex('Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious'))
```